# Compilation Error "Illegal Start of Type"

Tags: compilation

I am getting a compilation error each time I try to compile this code snippet. The error is "illegal start of type" and occurs at "for(int i=0;i

```
class hello
{ 
    int a[]={3,4,2,7,4,9,1,4,6,3};
    int n=a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<n-i-1;j++)
        { //Ascending Order
          if(a[j-1]>a[j])
            {
                int temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j-1];
                a[j-1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the error. I forgot to make a main method.